# Previous and next page in telegram bot with using InlineKeyboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

How to simplify the implementation of pages in the bot? I have three blocks - `"fire"`, `"right_arrow_fire"`, `"left_arrow_fire"` in `@bot.callback_query_handler`, and one of this is clearly superfluous. I studied similar questions on this site, and I realized what I'm can use `bot.edit_message_reply_markup`, but I can not figure out how to do it..

And, how made to not appear text "???" (in the line `bot.edit_message_text`) every time the page button is pressed.

Thanks you.
Full code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import telebot
from telebot import types
from telegram import (ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove)
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, Message

bot = telebot.TeleBot('********************************');

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)

    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Spell")    
    markup.add(item1)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hi", parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def value_search(message):

        if message.text == "Spell":

            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Fire", callback_data='fire')
            markup.add(item1)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Select element', reply_markup=markup)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Error")


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:                         
            if call.data == 'fire':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Fireball", callback_data='fireball')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Fire Wall", callback_data='firewall')
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Fire Arrow", callback_data='firearrow')
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Fire Explosion", callback_data='fireexplosion')
                item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Next Page --->", callback_data='right_arrow_fire')

                markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5)
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Select spell', reply_markup=markup)                  

            elif call.data == 'right_arrow_fire':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
                item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Fire Circle", callback_data='firecircle')
                item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Fire Elemental", callback_data='fireelemental')
                item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Fire Power", callback_data='firepower')
                item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Fire Storm", callback_data='firestorm')
                item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("<--- Previous Page", callback_data='left_arrow_fire')

                markup.add(item6, item7, item8, item9, item10)
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Select spell', reply_markup=markup)                  

            elif call.data == 'left_arrow_fire':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Fireball", callback_data='fireball')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Fire Wall", callback_data='firewall')
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Fire Arrow", callback_data='firearrow')
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Fire Explosion", callback_data='fireexplosion')
                item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Next Page --->", callback_data='right_arrow_fire')

                markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5)
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Select spell', reply_markup=markup)                  

            elif call.data == "fireball":
                bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=True, text="+1 damage")
            elif call.data == "firewall":
                bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=True, text="+2 damage")
            elif call.data == "firearrow":
                bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=True, text="+3 damage")
            elif call.data == "fireexplosion":
                bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=True, text="+4 damage")
            elif call.data == "firecircle":
                bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=True, text="+5 damage")
            elif call.data == "fireelemental":
                bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=True, text="+6 damage")
            elif call.data == "firepower":
                bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=True, text="+7 damage")
            elif call.data == "firestorm":
                bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=True, text="+8 damage")

            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='???', reply_markup=None)

    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the telebot docs for `bot.edit_message_reply_markup`,

```
       """
        Use this method to edit only the reply markup of messages.
        :param chat_id:
        :param message_id:
        :param inline_message_id:
        :param reply_markup:
        :return:
       """
```

In your case, you could implement this by,

```
bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup = markup)
```

Instead of,

```
bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Select spell', reply_markup=markup)
```

Only the InlineKeyboardButtons will be edited/updated, leaving the text as it is.